# what is the unit in ICO?

Tags: tokens, nft, ico, crowdsale, presale

It is a bit a silly question

I am trying to understand what the amount of coins are sold in ICO,

let's say, someone has minted 10 coins whose decimal are 3, which means someone has 10.000 (10 *10^3).

During the ICO, someone is willing to sell 1 coin for 1 wei.

Does it mean by 1,000(1 * 10^3) = 1 wei or 1(with no 10^3) = 1 wei?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the math is as follows,

1 coin = 1 * 10**3 = 1000

So 1 coin for ***1 wei = 1000 coins*** for 1 wei since the coin is of 3 decimals.

Hope this answers your question